# Hibernate/JPA unidirectional OneToMany with join condition on constant value in source table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, hibernate-annotations

I want to use Hibernate annotations to represent a unidirectional one-to-many relationship using a join. I want an added condition on the join so it only happens when a column in the *source* table (the "one") is equal to a constant value. For example.

```
SELECT *
FROM buildings b
LEFT JOIN building_floors bf on bf.building_id = b.id AND b.type = 'OFFICE'
```

I want to represent the `b.type = 'OFFICE'` part of that query.

My question is quite similar to this one, except I have a condition on the source table. [JPA/Hibernate Join On Constant Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818511/jpa-hibernate-join-on-constant-value)

The Java entities look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "buildings")
public class Building {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "buildingId",
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
            orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    // buildings.type = 'OFFICE'   ????
    private Set<BuildingFloors> buildingFloors;

    // getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "building_floors")
public class BuildingFloor {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "building_id")
    private int buildingId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "floor_id")
    private int floorId;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    // getters/setters
}
```

I've tried a few things where I have that placeholder comment:

#### @Where annotation

This doesn't work since that applies to the target entity.

#### @JoinColumns annotation

```
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "building_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "'OFFICE'", referencedColumnName = "type")
})
```

This doesn't work because I get the following error (simplified for clarity): `Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT * FROM buildings b JOIN building_floors bf on bf.building_id = b.id AND bf.'OFFICE' = b.type"`

#### A different @JoinColumns annotation

```
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "building_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "buildings.type", referencedColumnName = "'OFFICE'")
})
```

This doesn't work because when using a unidirectional OneToMany relationship, the referencedColumnName is from the source table. So I get the error: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: 'OFFICE' in buildings`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818511/jpa-hibernate-join-on-constant-value

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34546581/4754790

Comment: I don't get it. Since you are using a `JOIN`, and not a `LEFT JOIN`, why not using a direct where clause? `SELECT *
FROM buildings b
JOIN building_floors bf on bf.building_id = b.id WHERE b.type = 'OFFICE'`. What results do you expect?

Comment: Sorry! Please excuse my mistake. I did mean for my example query to be a `LEFT JOIN`. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not use [inheritance](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance) ? (I use it with JPA, I never use hibernate directly)

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@Table(name = "buildings")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
public class Building {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;
}
```

And :

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("OFFICE")
public class Office extends Building {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "buildingId",
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
        orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<BuildingFloors> buildingFloors;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'm pursuing this option now, but ran into an error in a unit test. The root cause in the stack trace is:
`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Invalid value "19" for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-176]`

Comment: Seems an error on your query, with invalid parameter type perhaps. I'm confident you will solve that.

Comment: I believe this error was happening because `type` is also a field on my `Building` entity. I had to add additional parameters to the Column annotation, and I stopped getting the error. `@Column(name = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I went with this approach and it's working.

Answer (score 4):

Create database View with the following select:

`SELECT bf.* FROM building_floors bf JOIN buildings b on bf.building_id = b.id AND b.type = 'OFFICE'`

Map it to a class `OfficeBuildingFloors` as an ordinary entity and then use `@OneToMany` for it in `Building` class.

Of course, you won't be able to modify such collection and to avoid any exception you can use `@Immutable` on `OfficeBuildingFloors`.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that! I'll find out if I'm able/allowed to create this view in my database.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should create a specific query to achieve your goals, rather than put specific annotations with constant parameter. I'm not see you mention another frameworks besides Hibernate so I would give some example with Hibernate. In your `Building` class your `unidirectional` mappings look like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.Lazy, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinTable(name = "building_floors", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "building_id")
private Set<BuildingFloor> buildingFloors;
```

Then you can fetch your data using `TypedQuery` like this.

```
TypedQuery<Customer> query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("select b from building b inner join fetch b.buildingFloors where b.type = 'OFFICE'", Building.class);
List<Building> result = query.getResultList();
```

My solutions is not Hibernate specific, actually you could perform this with simple JPA. Hope this can help you to achieve your goals.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The issue I have with this is that then I have to use this NamedQuery in all the various DAO methods I have that return the `Building` object. In my case that would be 20-30 separate places. I also have other entities that contain a reference to `Building` in them (e.g. a `Street` entity contains a Set of `Building`s.) Would I need to then create a different NamedQuery to return a `Street` so that it does the JOIN I want?

Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1):

As you want filter source table you could use @Loader annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "buildings")
@Loader(namedQuery = "building")
@NamedNativeQuery(name="building", 
    query="SELECT * FROM buildings b"
        + " LEFT JOIN building_floors bf on bf.building_id = b.id"
        + " WHERE b.type = 'OFFICE' AND b.id = ?",
    resultClass = Building.class)
class Building
```

Approach with view in DB would be better and more clearly, if it could be used inside DB also. Otherwise rename Building to something which explicitly represent filtering.

Another approaches to mention: @Filter, @FilterDef.