# JPA join with key transformation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

It is possible to tranform the primary key before a join with an hibernate annotation in addition to `@JoinColumn`?

For example:

Table Address(id, countryId) : data -> (1, EN), (2, EN), (3, FR)
Table Country(ref, label, language) : data -> (EN1, English, InEnglish), (EN2, Anglais, InFrench), (FR1, French, InEnglish), (FR2, Français, InFrench)

Java:

```
public class Address {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne (with transformation coutryId+"2" to join)
    private Country countryInFrench;
}
```

I don't know if I'm clear, do not hesitate to ask question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA/Hibernate Join On Constant Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818511/jpa-hibernate-join-on-constant-value)

Comment: I have seen this, but it is possible to transform current value ? if my address.coutryId = FR i want to do the join with FR1 so add 1 to the key before the join.

Comment: Probably not because this is a bad DB design and such anti patterns are not implemented by JPA

Comment: i suspected it... but i can't change de DB design... it's too old.

Comment: I think that you could use a @Formula to represent this conditional